# How to create a table in Python that has headers (text), filled with values (int and float)

Tags: python, arrays, string, csv, numpy

I am filling an numpy array in python (could change this to a list if neccesary), and i want to fill it with column headings, then enter a loop and fill the table with values, I am struggling with which type to use for the array. I have something like this so far...

```
 info = np.zeros(shape=(no_of_label+1,19),dtype = np.str)          #Creates array to store coordinates of particles
 info[0,:] = ['Xpos','Ypos','Zpos','NodeNumber','BoundingBoxTopX','BoundingBoxTopY','BoundingBoxTopZ','BoundingBoxBottomX','BoundingBoxBottomY','BoundingBoxBottomZ','BoxVolume','Xdisp','Ydisp','Zdisp','Xrot','Yrot','Zrot','CC','Error']

 for i in np.arange(1,no_of_label+1,1): 
     info[i,:] = [C[0],C[1],C[2],i,int(round(C[0]-b)),int(round(C[1]-b)),int(round(C[2]-b)),int(round(C[0]+b)),int(round(C[1]+b)),int(round(C[2]+b)),volume,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] # Fills an array with label.No., size of box, and co-ords

 np.savetxt(save_path+Folder+'/Data_'+Folder+'.csv',information,fmt = '%10.5f' ,delimiter=",")
```

There is other things in the loop, but they are irrelevent, C is an array of float, b is int.

I also need to be able to save it as a csv file as shown in the last line, and open it in excel.

What I have now, returns all the values as integers, when i need C[0], C[1], C[2] to be floating point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You understand that when you save as a CSV file you are saving text - csv files are text.

Comment: Yes I realise that, the next step of the process though is to input the csv file, and it needs to be exactly in the format stated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it as follows:

```
info = np.zeros(shape=(no_of_label+1,19),dtype=float)

for i in np.arange(1,no_of_label+1,1):
    info[i-1] = [C[0],C[1],C[2],i,int(round(C[0]-b)),int(round(C[1]-b)),int(round(C[2]-b)),int(round(C[0]+b)),int(round(C[1]+b)),int(round(C[2]+b)),volume,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

np.savetxt(save_path+Folder+'/Data_'+Folder+'.csv',information,fmt = '%10.5f' ,delimiter=",",header='Xpos,Ypos,Zpos,NodeNumber,BoundingBoxTopX,BoundingBoxTopY,BoundingBoxTopZ,BoundingBoxBottomX,BoundingBoxBottomY,BoundingBoxBottomZ,BoxVolume,Xdisp,Ydisp,Zdisp,Xrot,Yrot,Zrot,CC,Error',comments='')
```

Using the header function built in to the numpy save text feature. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do with this array but I think you want to use 'dtype=object' instead of 'np.str'. You can do that explicitly, by changing 'np.str' to 'dtype' or here is how I would write the first part of your code:

```
import numpy as np

labels = ['Xpos','Ypos','Zpos','NodeNumber','BoundingBoxTopX','BoundingBoxTopY',
                    'BoundingBoxTopZ','BoundingBoxBottomX','BoundingBoxBottomY','BoundingBoxBottomZ',
                    'BoxVolume','Xdisp','Ydisp','Zdisp','Xrot','Yrot','Zrot','CC','Error']
no_of_label = len(labels)

#make a list of length ((no_of_label+1)*19) and convert it to an array and reshape it
info = np.array([None]*((no_of_label+1)*19)).reshape(no_of_label+1, 19)
info[0] = labels
```

Again, there is probably a better way of doing this if you have a specific application in mind, but this should let you store different types of data in the same 2D array.

Comment: yes, dtype object works a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: Actually what you suggest gives me this error when i try to save as cvs file..

% (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f,%10.5f')